# I need to create a program that will look through a file directory to search for duplicates

Tags: c#

I need to create a program that will look through a file directory to search for duplicates which will then show the user in a form using a checklistbox and a list box and place the dubes in the checked list box and then none dupes in the listbox. I am a entire noob to C# and I have only really done Python before. Help would be nice, this is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace File_existence
{
public partial class fileForm : Form
{
    private string _filelistlocation;

    public fileForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void fileForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _filelistlocation = "C:\\temp\\clientactivityfiles.txt";
    }

    public static FileStream Open(
        string _filelistlocation,
        FileMode Read);


    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // open _filelistlocation
        // foreach line in _filelistlocation
        // concatenate pat hand filename
        //
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Temp\Trade Files\processed\filetest1.txt"))
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Yes");
            System.Console.WriteLine("The file exists");

        //StreamReader files= new StreamReader(File)();

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Sorry I should have been more specific. I Have been told that it is possible in my database that there are files with different names and duplicates or same names but different folders and I need to develop this to find them to then be taken out later.

Comment: By duplicates you mean file with the same name or with the same content, because there can be several files with the same name in one directory?

Comment: How could there be duplicates in a directory? Only one file with a specific name can exist in a given directory. Are you talking about reading the contents of a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it gets you names of all duplicated files in duplicates variable:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryToCheck = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\test");

FileInfo[] files= directoryToCheck.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var duplicates= files.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                        .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                        .Select(group => group.Key);
```

Comment: Whereabouts should I place this in the code? I have tried in about 3 different areas and it gave me errors. Thanks

Comment: You have a directory where you store all your files, right? So this is a template for how to create check for the duplicates. If your directory is: C:\Temp\Trade Files\processed so change C:\test into it and if you want to check only specific file - set name of it instead of "*.*".  You can put this code in button1_Click and if duplicates isn't empty - than the same file exists in your directory.

Comment: I placed it just below the private void button1_Click and I have changed the file directory to (@"C:\\temp") but when I run it nothing has changed? I am sure it is obvios but This is my first big/bigger project on C# and it is quite different to Python; the only language I am proficient in. Thanks for your help -

Comment: No problem) this code just put all duplicates in variable, you have to do something with it. For example: if (duplicates.Count() > 0){System.Console.WriteLine("The file exists")}

Comment: For better understanding the code - put the breakpoint and look what values you receive....

Comment: Thank you very much it works better now.(I also added in: MessageBox.Show("Insert msg here") I am about 1/2 way through the project. Would you mind if I comment here if I need more help? Its ok if you don't want me to but as a beginner given such a hard task  might need help. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I will answer if I have an opportunity. If this answer is ok for you - mark it as an answer so others won't spend time thinking how to help you.

Comment: I have selected your answer as the most helpful :D

Comment: OK next I need to make the duplicates show in the checked listbox which I assume is checkedListBox1.Items.Add("duplicate") and then give the user the option to move or to copy. <--- No idea how to do.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you need to use brackets for block statements:

```
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Temp\Trade Files\processed\filetest1.txt"))
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Yes");
            System.Console.WriteLine("The file exists");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you mean to compare the contents of the files because a directory can only contain 1 file of a specific path.

Look into System.IO Functions.

You can get a list of files in a directory using `Directory.GetFiles()` which will return a list of paths.

You can then check each file's content against the rest to compile a List ([See generic lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) eg `List<string>`). The functions `File.ReadAllBytes()` and `File.ReadAllLines()` might help you but comparing files will be dependant on what the file types are - there are a number of ways.